# Upload and save image into firebase Storage flutter dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

i'm trying to upload picture and register user information into firebase storage and firestore the problem is it's not accepting this code for some reason it says i need to put `;` after `_registerUser()`
here is the code i'm using to save and upload information :

```
 Future<void> uploadAndSaveImage() async {
if (_imageFile != null) {
  _passwordTextEditingController.text ==
          _cPasswordTextEditingController.text
      ? _emailTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
              _passwordTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
              _cPasswordTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
              _nameTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
          ?uploadToStorage() , _registerUser()
          : displayDialog("Please fill up the registration complete form..")
      : displayDialog("Password do not match.");
} else {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: ((c) {
        return ErrorAlertDialog(
          message: "Please select an image.",
        );
      }));
}
```

}

the regiser user function :

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

void _registerUser() async {
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

```
await _auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
  password: _passwordTextEditingController.text.trim(),
)
    .then((auth) {
  firebaseUser = auth.user;
}).catchError((error) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (c) {
        return ErrorAlertDialog(
          message: error.message.toString(),
        );
      });
});
if (firebaseUser != null) {
  saveUserInfoToFireStore(firebaseUser).then((value) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => StoreHome());
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
  });
}
```

}

Ps: i'm still new to this it's my third app with flutter

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to upload the user image from local storage to Firebase with `uid` as the reference name.

```
final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final imgPicker = ImagePicker();
  File image;
  String photoUrl = "";
  bool _uploading = false;

  uploadPic() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _uploading = true;
      });

      // picking Image from local storage
      final file = await imgPicker.getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );

      if (file != null) {
        image = File(file.path);
      } else {  
        setState(() {
          _uploading = false;
        });
      }

      // creating ref at Firebase Storage with userID
      Reference ref =
          firebaseStorage.ref(_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid).child("dp");

      ref.putFile(image).whenComplete(() {
        print("Pic Uploaded Successfully!");
        setState(() {
          _uploading = false;
        });
        // refreshing the UI when photo updated
        getUploadedPic();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

After uploading you may get the image URL as follow:

```
  getUploadedPic() async {
    // getting dp URL link
    photoUrl = await firebaseStorage
        .ref("${_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid}/dp")
        .getDownloadURL()
        .whenComplete(() => print("URL UPLOADED AT: $photoUrl"));

  }
```